# Django docs with the new style?

Tags: django

Django online documentation, is [using  a new style](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2014/dec/15/announcing-django-website-redesign/), but when I generate the latest one using Sphinx, I only get the old styled one.

How do I generate the  new styled one? is there a public-available  theme  for sphinx to do that?

Edit: there is a Sphinx theme, called [Basicstrap](http://pythonhosted.org/sphinxjp.themes.basicstrap/), but it dont give the same results.

Comment: @alecxe i generate them from here https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the offline docs use an entirely separate layout/theme so the new styles would need to be copied manually over here: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/docs/_theme/djangodocs

Comment: but even if i generate it, i get this http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ywav.jpg and the `conf.py` the theme shows to that folder, so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This looks expected. The new styles have not been ported over to the offline theme at this time.

Comment: I hope they will include it soon, because it is beautiful ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can build styled documentation by building djangoproject.com site on your own. The site sources are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com). App resposible for documentation is [docs](https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com/tree/master/docs).